# Excel VBA call DLL developed using MPI

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll, mpi

I am new to C++. And I want to develop a dll of a function applying Monte Carlo Simulation using VS C++ 2013. I want to enhance the monte carlo capacity. So I want to use Microsoft MS-MPI and HPC 2008 to do parallel computing within this dll. Then, I need to call this dll in Excel VBA.

- Is it possible to do it?
- When excuting a C++ code using ms-mpi, I can use "mpiexec.exe" to tell computer how many cores to run. If in Excel Vba, I want the dll to run on multiple cores, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to use MPI? Unless you want to target clusters and supercomputers, and those running Windows are really few, perhaps OpenMP, Intel TBB, or the Concurency Runtime will be much more suitable choices.

Comment: Because the end user only has excel on windows system. I need to develop this dll for them to use in Excel Vba.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. MPI (Message Passing Interface) is a technique for programming distributed memory systems, i.e. systems that consist of multiple compute nodes with no shared memory, addressable by all nodes. If you just want to use the power of a single multicore/multisocket computer, then MPI is not the right choice.